# Bad state: GetIt: Object/factory with type is not registered inside GetIt

Tags: flutter

I have been using [GetIt](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) for a long time now, but have suddentky run nto a problem I fail to understand.

I have my main.dart:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  setupGetIt();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

My GetIt helper:

```
final GetIt di = GetIt.instance;

void setupGetIt() {
  di.registerLazySingleton<RoastTimer>(() => RoastTimerImpl());
}
```

Then in a widget I do this, and this is where the exception is thrown:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _roastTimer = di<RoastTimer>();
  }
```

I have run with debugger and verified that my "registerLazySingleton" does indeed get called before any Widgets are rendered, so this is a puzzle to me?

I have also tried just doing:

```
_roastTimer = RoastTimerImpl();
```

Just to test if that would work, and indeed it does work. So it is only the GetIt part that is not working.

But if I keep everything in my GetIt helper, and do this in my main.dart:

```
di.registerLazySingleton<RoastTimer>(() => RoastTimerImpl());
```

It also works just fine...?? It is as if the method 'setupGetIt' in my GetIt helper is not working, but how can that be???

I am obviously missing something here, I just can not spot it? Any ideas?

Best regards
Søren

Comment: what is di()?. Why you are assigning di() to _roastTimer?

Comment: di is a instance of GetIt, I am not assigning di() to _roastTimer, I am using GetIt to create a instance og RoastTimerImpl

Answer (score -1):

You should access the singleton class in this way

```
di<RoastTimerImpl>()
```

Final code wiil be as follows:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  
  // change here
  _roastTimer=di<RoastTimerImpl>();
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to encod the < and >, the question has been updated